# How to find critical points of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Say I have a function

$$g(x) = \int_a^b (f(t)-x)^3dt$$

how would I go about finding the critical points of this function?

I know that FTC gives you that if

$$h(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$$ then $$h'(x) = f(x)$$

but I just keep thinking that

$$g(x) = (f(b)-x) - (f(a)-x)$$

so wouldn't the derivative be 0? And since you find critical points where g'(x)=0 wouldn't that mean everywhere is a critical point?

I know this can't be true but having hard time figuring out what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to figure out where $g'$ is zero, compute it as
\begin{align*}
g'(x) &= -3\int_a^b\, (f(t) - x)^2\, dt \\
&= -3\int_a^b\, f^2(t)\, dt + 6x \int_a^b f(t)\, dt -3x^2(b - a).
\end{align*}
It's a quadratic in $x$. Set it to zero and solve for the $x$s that are the critical points.

If you set $I_0 = b - a$, $I_1 = \int_a^b\, f(t)\, dt$, $I_2 = \int_a^b\, f^2(t)\, dt$ your critical points occur at
\begin{equation*}
\hat{x} = \frac{I_1}{I_0} \pm \sqrt{\biggl( \frac{I_1}{I_0}\biggr)^2 - \frac{I_2}{I_0}}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense, but just wondering cause some of those variables are integrals, how would I know wether each point is a min or max or neither?

Comment: @JohnOkley: Second derivative test.